# Is using singleton for React Router secure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm using `react-router-dom` for routing on a React webapp with just a few pages. I would like to prevent the user from accessing certain pages if they haven't used OAuth2 to sign in with their Google account yet, so I wanted to use a `ProtectedRoute` component like so:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={SignIn}/>
    <ProtectedRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I've seen a lot of tutorials recommending using a singleton like a global variable, context, or class instance passed through the component tree to check login status. Couldn't someone just go into developer tools and change the context? Ex. changing `isLoggedIn:false` to `true`.

I'm using a global instance of `socket.io` for the server connection, so reloading the page isn't ideal. The Express backend server stores a JWT for verification if you leave the page and come back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protected routes don't exist to *securely* prevent the client from accessing those pages. Protected routes exist as a *user interface pattern* to generally prevent users from seeing or accessing certain UI unless they are logged in and/or authorized.

If you are relying on a JavaScript boolean flag to prevent users from accessing private information or an admin control panel, that is incredibly insecure and you are doing it wrong. The *actual* security of your app should be handled by the server and JWT. Every single request to your server or API that could involve sensitive information or actions should be authenticated with a secure token. That way, even if a user maliciously (or even erroneously) sets their `isAdmin` flag to `true` and accesses `mywebsite.com/admin`, they can't *do or see* anything sensitive there because they don't have the correct auth token to do a `GET` request on `mywebsite.com/api/getSecretUserList` or whatever. Maybe they can force their way to `mywebsite.com/admin`, but so what? They'd just see an error, or a blank page, or whatever because the privileged network requests (should) fail.